# I want to get 4466353 in response to set Environment Variable in postman

Tags: postman

I have a response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "1001002": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "article_id": 4466353,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466305,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466339,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466290,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466309,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466302,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466278,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466271,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466291,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                },
                {
                    "article_id": 4466250,
                    "off_thumb": 0,
                    "thumbnail_url": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this `pm.environment.set("article_id", pm.response.json().data['1001002'].data[0].article_id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
let response = pm.response.json();

response.data['1001002'].data.forEach(function(cam) {
    if(cam.article_id == 4466353) {
       pm.environment.set("article_id", cam.article_id);
    }
});
```